# mod_rewrite all robots.txt requests to default file, server-wide

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2, robots.txt

So, I have a development server running OpenSuse with apache. There are loads of projects on this server, some of them have an online/live counterpart.

Each project has a separate subdomain.

**How do I rewrite all requests for robots.txt to one "default"-file**, server wide?

My goal is to prevent indexing from search-bots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *believe* there is no easier way than to set an `Alias` in every `VirtualHost` directive:

```
Alias /robots.txt /home/path/to/generic/robots.txt
```

I'm happy to stand corrected by a truly global solution, though.

Comment: I am truly amazed!

I actually have two servers with same problem, but the one at home use 'dynamic_vhosts', so all requests got through the same `VirtualHost` = Global change.

The one at work use a template to make the .vhost files. So regex can fix the old ones, and changing the template fix future ones.

Stackoverflow blew me away, I've never gotten an answer this fast before!

Thanks a million!

Comment: @Andre well, that's Stack Overflow for ya :) There simply is a *lot* of people around at any given time. Nice that this worked already.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem and found that I could place the Alias declaration that Pekka suggests in the httpd.conf outside of the VirutalHost directive and it applied to all sites.